# Should you use a conjuncton in a question?

Tags: conjunctions, question-mark

Example:

> What do you think of this as I was going to buy it?

Alternative I suspect is correct:

> What do you think of this?
> I was going to buy it.

I wanted to see if I can word it as a single sentence.
Verbally I'd say:

> What do you think of this? as I was going to buy it.

This feels wrong regardless of if 'as' is the start of a new sentence or not.
You aren't meant to start a sentence with a conjunction and you can't have a question end in the middle of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You have a question and a statement.

- Question: "What do you think of this?"
- Statement: "I was going to buy it."

When the statement merely provides background information to the question, it isn't part of the question and can therefore sound awkward when tacked on with a connecting "as".

You can change the statement to a relative clause and link it parenthetically:

- What do you think of this, which I was going to buy?

With a little more work, you don't even need the parenthetical construct:

- What do you think of this item (that) I was going to buy?

Answer (score 0):

If the subordinate clause ("as I was going to buy it") were part of the syntax of the rest of the sentence, then there wouldn't be a problem. This issue arises because it is a "disjunct" (some people might call it a "sentence adverb(ial)", etc.), standing "outside" of the preceding main clause, which actually asks the question.

Lawrence provides some good single-sentence alternatives in his answer. Another possibility is to make the subordinate clause parenthetical, making clear to the reader that it is not part of the syntax of the preceding clause:

> What do you think of this (as I was going to buy it)?

Yet another option is simply to move the subordinate clause away from the question mark:

> As I was going to buy this, what do you think of it?

Neither of these sentences requires changing any words from your original version. However, a drawback of the second is that a reader might think that "as" meant "at the same time as" and then become confused upon encountering a present tense verb ("do") in the main clause.

---

> You aren't meant to start a sentence with a conjunction

I've never seen such a rule from a reputable source. I think that you are referring to the "rule" that you shouldn't start a sentence with a coordinating conjunction (correlatives typically excepted). That rule is much disputed, and in any case "as" doesn't act as a coordinating conjunction here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful question.  The first version is the best, that has nothing to do with the grammar.  Sometimes the connection between one statement and another is so obvious that it needs explanation.  So in this case, *as* is not necessary. It is evident that **the point** of my saying that I was going to buy  'this' was to explain why I was asking the question.  So to put in the 'as', though the point of what I went on to say were not obvious looks naïve or a little awkward.

You might equally reverse the order and say:

> I was going to buy this:  what do you think of it?

Again, in this case the connection between the two is too obvious to require the word *so* and say

> I was going to buy this: so what do you think of it.

As with the previous version, the 'so' looks redundant.  The juxtaposition does the explanatory job by itself.